# Where can find all google maps v3 event list?

Tags: google-maps

As title, I searched official google maps api reference and other site, I can't find a doc list comprehensive available events. Please give me a hint to get all the v3 events. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

[List of all events (with demo)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview)

Comment: Thank you very much, these are already I know. But it didn't list whole available events.

Comment: Are you sure? There are quite a few there and if it is not in the API docs, I'm not sure you'll find it elsewhere. Is there something specific you're after?

Comment: You are right, man. I got big eyes. I finally saw the events table within each class. At first I suppose there is an independent section to list event, but actually not. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 26):

In the Google Maps API docs, for **[google.maps.Map class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)** [no direct listing sorry, but scroll down a bit] there are a list of events which the Map itself will fire. The events are:

- bounds_changed
- center_changed
- click
- dblclick
- drag
- dragend
- dragstart
- heading_changed
- idle
- maptypeid_changed
- mousemove
- mouseout
- mouseover
- projection_changed
- resize
- rightclick
- tilesloaded
- tilt_changed
- zoom_changed

Answer (score 2):

best to look at the API reference for the map object itself:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). I copied them all out, sorted and de-duped them.

- `addfeature`
- `animation_changed`
- `bounds_changed`
- `center_changed`
- `circlecomplete`
- `click`
- `clickable`
- `clickable_changed`
- `closeclick`
- `content_changed`
- `cursor_changed`
- `dblclick`
- `defaultviewport_changed`
- `directions_changed`
- `domready`
- `drag`
- `dragend`
- `draggable`
- `draggable_changed`
- `dragstart`
- `editable`
- `flat_changed`
- `geodesic`
- `heading_changed`
- `icon_changed`
- `icons`
- `idle`
- `insert_at`
- `map`
- `maptypeid_changed`
- `markercomplete`
- `mousedown`
- `mousemove`
- `mouseout`
- `mouseover`
- `mouseup`
- `overlaycomplete`
- `pano_changed`
- `path`
- `place_changed`
- `places_changed`
- `polygoncomplete`
- `polylinecomplete`
- `position_changed`
- `pov_changed`
- `projection_changed`
- `radius_changed`
- `rectanglecomplete`
- `remove_at`
- `removefeature`
- `removeproperty`
- `resize`
- `rightclick`
- `set_at`
- `setgeometry`
- `setproperty`
- `shape_changed`
- `status_changed`
- `strokeColor`
- `strokeOpacity`
- `strokeWeight`
- `tilesloaded`
- `tilt_changed`
- `title_changed`
- `visible`
- `visible_changed`
- `zIndex`
- `zindex_changed`
- `zoom_changed`

Answer (score 0):

there is a good reference for Google Maps Api events:

[**Google Maps Javascript API V3 Events**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html)

Comment: please dont just copy links here, put the content of the link, and leave the link as reference.