# How to fire action when ANY Google Map Event Has Been Fired

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing an app using Google Maps API 3.  I would like to know what is the best implementation in dealing with this problem.  I want to execute an action once ANY event in Google Map has been fired.  Currently, what I am doing is that I call the function every time a specific event is called. I find this redundant and I have to make a listener for all of the events. So, is there a way to generalize this where I can do the following:

```
google.maps.addListener(everything_on_the_map_canvas, 'ANY_EVENT', function(event) {
  foo();
})

function foo(){
 //do something here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the action you are performing? I can't think of a real-world use case for this requirement.

Comment: I have a hidden div above the map which is only displayed over the map upon clicking of a link.  I would like to hide the div again once the user decides to continue with the map operations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user decides to continue with map operations, they will have to move the mouse over the map to do anything. So you could simply trap a `mousemove`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {foo();})
```

If the user can manipulate the map without moving the mouse over the map, then you will need to listen to other events.

- `bounds_changed` will cover most eventualities with zoom and pan, heading and the like
- `maptype_id_changed`

But that's only three instead of all of them. If the bounds don't change when the tilt does (and you can change tilt from outside the map) you may need to listen for `tilt_changed` as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. So, I assume that there is no specific mother event that can be called to do this?

Comment: @nmenego: No. I expect you've looked at the documentation though.

Comment: I did, and what I have done was to call the ones in this list: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597806/where-can-find-all-google-maps-v3-event-list). Thanks anyway. :)